# What is the most performant solution for casting or copying an IEnumerable<enum:int> to int[] in C#?

Tags: c#, generics, enums

What would be the most performant solution for casting or copying a List of an enumeration, where the enumeration inherits from int, to an integer array?

Comment: What language are you using?

Comment: Please next time avoid using "best" in your questions - in most cases there is no way to know what you want - most elegant code, fastest possible, most reliable, shortest code, coolest code, least memory usage...

Comment: Question title and question edited per feedback.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since you don't specify what language you're using, I'm guessing you're using C#. I'll also assume you're talking about enumerations rather than enumerables:

```
var array = enums.Select(e => (int)e).ToArray();
```

Comment: That is the `List<enum>` that is your source.

Answer (score 3):

It's not possible in general to "convert" an `List<anything>` into an array.  It is possible to produce a new array whose contents are initialized with values which are based upon the list contents.  This is distinct from e.g. converting a `List<T>` to a `ReadOnlyCollection<T>`, which yields a read-only "live" view of the original data.  This distinction is important, since in the latter situation the resulting array will remain "attached" to the object that supplied the initialization data, while in the former situation it will be detached.

It is possible to copy data from an array of an enumerated type to an array of the underlying integer type using the `Array.Copy` method.  Your best bet may be to use `ToArray` to convert the `List<someEnum>` into a `someEnum[]`, and then use `Array.Copy` to copy the data from that into an `int[]` (or `long[]`, or whatever type would be appropriate).  Although that would require copying the array twice, in general the time required to bulk-copy array elements will much be less than the time to handle elements individually.

Answer (score 1):

The most perfomant would be to run a `for` loop yourself.

```
static int[] Array(List<MyEnum> list)
{
    var array = new int[list.Count];
    for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
        array[i] = (int)list[i];

    return array;
}
```

---

You can make the whole thing short with `Cast<T>` extension method in `System.Linq`. It would cause boxing and wont be the most performant.

```
var array = list.Cast<int>().ToArray();
```

---

Justin's is the best solution considering readability/speed trade off.